# Laravel & angular Get image from Request

Tags: php, angular, laravel, file-upload

I have an angular form that contain many fields and one of this fields is image.when I am sending this data as Object Request to backend(laravel) give me error 500 because cant find the image(file).

I tried it without any data just the image(file) its worked with this code:

```
public function insertFile(Request $request){
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $originalImage = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $file->move(public_path('images'), $originalImage);
   }
```

> Now I am trying to get the image(file) from CompanyDetails Object
> field image

> TypeScript object

```
export class CompanyDetails {
      user_id?:any;
      companyName: string;
      managerName: string;
      image?: any;
    }
```

> this my object after assign data in object

```
private buildForm(){
    this.detailsModel.companyName = this.myForm.companyDetails.value.companyName;
    this.detailsModel.managerName = this.myForm.companyDetails.value.managerName;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file' , this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);
    this.detailsModel.image = formData;
}
```

> this is my php (laravel) code

```
public function insertDetails(Request $request){
        $data = $request->input();
        $managerName= $data['managerName'];
        $description= $data['description'];
        //get image from request
        $image= $data['image'];
        $file = $image->hasFile('file');
        $originalImage = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $imagePath = 'public/uploads/'.$originalImage;
        $imageName = $originalImage;
        $file->move(public_path('images'), $originalImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with reactive forms.
As you can see here I use the toFormData() method before sending it to the backend.

I don't know if it helps you but let me know.

```js
export class ContactFormularComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm: FormGroup;

  mailAddresses = environment.contactMailAddresses;

  constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService, 
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      name: new FormControl(null),
      subject: new FormControl(null),
      message: new FormControl(null),
      attachement: new FormControl(null),
      receiver: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  send() {
    if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      
      var data = toFormData(this.contactForm.value);
      this.contactService.sendMail(data).subscribe((response) => {
        this._snackBar.open(response['message'], 'Ok', {
          duration: 5000,
          panelClass: 'snackbar-success'
        });
      },
      (response)=>{
        this._snackBar.open(response['message'], 'Ok', {
          duration: 5000,
          panelClass: 'snackbar-success'
        });
      });
      this.initForm();
    }
  }
}

export function toFormData<T>( formValue: T ) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for ( const key of Object.keys(formValue) ) {
    const value = formValue[key];
    formData.append(key, value);
  }
  return formData;
}
```